# How to tell the difference between heat shrink tape and normal wire tape?

Tags: insulation

Heat shrink tape

[image]

Wire tape
[image]

They look exactly the same, especially with the absence of any markings on the ring...  How can I tell the difference between the two?

Comment: Apply some heat and see if it shrinks?

Comment: That was what i was about to post :)

Comment: Test it then label the inside of the core

Answer (score 1):

talking from my experience with thermal shrinking tubes id thermal shrinking tape tends to be less shiny than the common one

Comment: And the normal one is usually stickier...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162459)

Comment: @laptop2d the question asked for a difference : the words "less shiny" seem to answer that...

Comment: Looks like a comment to me, but then again they don't show the question in review. Needless to say, this answer could use some cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

Heat shrink tape is 3+ times thicker and far more stiff.